# How to change font sizes in blogdown website?

Tags: css, r-markdown, font-size, blogdown

I have a `blogdown` [website](https://kartrick.rbind.io/) using the Hugo Apero theme. I have tried downloading and [changing the fonts listed](https://github.com/rikudoukarthik/rikudou/commit/3dcb063682bbd608aeff780ee16393b3fa71bb16#diff-c1067537b21809e598966db5125757a339845ee623ce94cfe59ab21086f1f92dL36) (selecting larger sized font files) in the custom SCSS file in `assets/`, but this hasn't changed the font size of my blog text.

Moreover, I realise that different pages render the text in slightly different font sizes, and yet I am unable to locate where all this configuration happens. For instance, my home and [about](https://kartrick.rbind.io/about/) pages have a slightly bigger font size than the [talks](https://kartrick.rbind.io/talk/) page and even [blog posts](https://kartrick.rbind.io/blog/).

Any advice on playing with fonts and font sizes that goes beyond [this](https://hugo-apero-docs.netlify.app/learn/fonts/#use-a-custom-font) would be very useful!